# Inserting and removing into/from sorted list in Python

Tags: python, list, binary-search

I have a sorted list of integers, L, and I have a value X that I wish to insert into the list such that L's order is maintained. Similarly, I wish to quickly find and remove the first instance of X.

Questions:

1. How do I use the bisect module to do the first part, if possible?
2. Is L.remove(X) going to be the most efficient way to do the second part? Does Python detect that the list has been sorted and automatically use a logarithmic removal process?

Example code attempts:

```
i = bisect_left(L, y)

L.pop(i)                 #works
del L[bisect_left(L, i)] #doesn't work if I use this instead of pop
```

Comment: Your exmaple makes no sense; `i` is an index into `L`, but `L.pop(i)` removes a *value* from the list.

Comment: That's false, removes the index

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. You use the [`bisect.insort()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort):

   ```
   bisect.insort(L, X)
   ```
2. `L.remove(X)` will scan the whole list until it finds `X`. Use `del L[bisect.bisect_left(L, X)]` instead (provided that `X` is indeed in `L`).

Note that removing from the middle of a list is still going to incur a cost as the elements from that position onwards all have to be shifted left one step. A binary tree might be a better solution if that is going to be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: So for #1, right now I have, for example, L.append(X); L=sorted(L); but this can be replaced with insort(L,X)?

Comment: @MrP: Yes; the `bisect` module will use bisection to find the insertion point, a O(log n) operation, versus O(n log n) for appending and sorting.

Comment: For #2 I just tried replacing L.pop(X) with del L[bisect_left(L, X)] and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: From docs: Keep in mind that the `O(log n)` search is dominated by the slow `O(n)` insertion step. So, `insort` is actually `O(N)`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: which is still better than O(n log n). The average case will be 0.5n, of course; insertion and deletion both incur cost as you shift items left or right to make room. Again, a btree would solve that issue.

Comment: Random side-question, but is there a way to use bisect to emulate the search for the index in L where L[i] is greater than or equal to B? Right now I am just doing a naive iteration from index 0

Comment: @MrP: Did you read the `bisect` documentation at all? All functions in that module take both lower and upper bounds.

Comment: @MartijnPieters As in it doesn't seem to remove what it needs to remove (the resulting code crashes, index errors and such)

Comment: @MrP: I tested with `L = [0, 1, 2]` and `del L[bisect_left(L, 1)]` which removed `1`, as expected, from `L`.

Comment: I read the documentation but I do not understand it. I have a really hard time figuring out what is meant most of the time, function parameters too abstract, much easier with brute examples

Comment: @MrP: An `IndexError` indicates that `X` was not present in `L`, and `X` was larger than any value currently in `L`.

Comment: @MrP: But if you have `B`, first search for that value using `bisect` methods, then use that index as a lower bound for the next search (set `lo` to the index from which `bisect` needs to start searching).

Comment: @MrP: without seeing what you tried that is impossible to answer. What type of object is `X`? Did you assert that `X in L` is `True`? What index did `bisect.bisect_left(L, X)` return? You need to try these things out in a interactive prompt. Play with them. Understand the implications, what it does *exactly*.

Comment: I will update the OP to show what I mean because I don't understand why this isn't working

Comment: @MrP: Perhaps you need to create a *new* question. If your problem domain keeps shifting, we'll never be done with this one.

Comment: It's the exact same question so I feel it is appropriate to keep it limited to this thread's scope

Comment: @MrP: This is not a thread; this is a question with attached answers. We are already stretching the comments beyond the limits, really.

Comment: Nevermind, found my error. Just needed to replace the whole thing with del curp[bisect_left(curp, y)]

Answer (score 2):

You could use Raymond Hettinger's [IndexableSkiplist](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576930-efficient-running-median-using-an-indexable-skipli/). It performs 3 operations in `O(ln n)` time:

- insert value
- remove value
- lookup value by rank

---

```
import skiplist
import random
random.seed(2013)

N = 10
skip = skiplist.IndexableSkiplist(N)
data = range(N)
random.shuffle(data)
for num in data:
    skip.insert(num)

print(list(skip))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for num in data[:N//2]:
    skip.remove(num)

print(list(skip))
# [0, 3, 4, 6, 9]
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the index of the first number that is >= B?

Comment: You can use `bisect.bisect_left(skip, B)`. Note that if `B` is strictly bigger than any value in `skip`, then `bisect_left` will return `len(skip)`, which is outside the range of valid index values for `skip`.